# What work item to select in Azure Devops Server (TFS)

Tags: azure-devops

I'm fairly new to the different work items available in Azure Devops Server 2020 (TFS) and wonder if I could get some advice on what to select.

I am the only developer in a project and have direct contact with the stakeholder. When the stakeholder report an issue should I then create an Issue/impediment that describes whats is wrong or needs to be changed. And then create a task or bug that I link to that issue/impediment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Agile Glossary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/agile-glossary?view=azure-devops) to get some information.

Issues/Impediments:

> A type of work item that helps track unplanned activities. Resolving
> an issue or impediment requires more work beyond what was scheduled
> based on actual requirements.

Bugs:

> A type of work item that records a potential source of dissatisfaction
> with the product.

You can use Bugs to report issues from your stakeholders and here you also use two ways:

1. Use bugs on the requirements level and create tasks under it.
2. Use bugs on tasks level and link them to affected user story or product backlog item.

[Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

Or you can use user stories/product backlog items as a record to enhance your product.